# Data for depth contours/DEM for Mediterranean sea

Tags: data, dem, bathymetry

I am searching for data for depth contours for the Mediterranean sea, especially the Aegean sea in any format (raster, shp). Does anyone know if there are any free available data?

Comment: If you are seeking open data then I think the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is the place to ask your question.

Comment: Try out https://www.gebco.net/ Openseamap uses this as source

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [EMODnet](http://portal.emodnet-bathymetry.eu) and especially their bathymetry portal/services with data for view and download.